# can't access property on parent scope, however I can see through that chain of properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a property called `itemClickHandler` on an isolate scope. Then I have few other scopes that inherit from it including scopes created by `ng-repeat` directive. Neither of the child scopes create isolate scope so I should be able to access this property on child scope, but for some reason I can't. Why?
This works:

```
scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.itemClickHandler //returns value
```

This doesn't work:

```
scope.itemClickHandler //returns undefined
```

Comment: Can you make a plunkr? Hard to determine the exact issue without seeing all of the controllers and scopes in play

Comment: @tymeJV, I'm using [this plugin](https://github.com/davidjnelson/angular-accordion/blob/master/src/main/webapp/js/lib/angular-accordion.js). I've just added the following `itemClickHandler: "="` to the scope of `angularAccordion` and passing this callback in html like this `<angular-accordion item-click-handler="addNode">`. I'm trying to access this callback inside `paneHeader` directive's link function.

Comment: seems that somewhere u have scope.itemClickHandler = undefined, then this scope value will change, whean sceop.$parent will not

Comment: @tymeJV, I suspect that `ng-transclude` which is added by directives in the plugin may have something to do with it. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Normally, your code sample would work, but as you say yourself, you're inside an isolated scope. By definition, isolate scopes are removed from the prototype chain (quote from the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)):

> Normally, a scope prototypically inherits from its parent. An isolated scope does not. See the "Directive Definition Object - scope" section for more information about isolate scopes.